# Ionic Run Faild

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework

I can run my ionic project on android device perfectly until now but now this error is happens. I did not change anything in project structure.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugCompile'.
> Could not find any version that matches org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta:13+.
 Searched in the following locations:
     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library_beta/maven-metadata.xml
     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library_beta/
     https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library_beta/maven-metadata.xml
     file:/Applications/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library_beta/maven-metadata.xml
     file:/Applications/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library_beta/
     file:/Applications/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library_beta/maven-metadata.xml
     file:/Applications/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library_beta/
 Required by:
     :android:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 20.525 secs

/Users/myuser/Projects/appname/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error code 1 for command: /Users/myuser/Projects/appname/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/myuser/Projects/appname/platforms/android/build.gradle,-PcdvBuildArch=x86,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
```

I removed `android platform` and all `node_modules` and added them again but still i see this error.
i can `serve` my app and run on IOS simulator perfectly.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with crosswalk. Try to remove everything related to it. Maybe `ionic browser revert android` will solve it.

Comment: sometimes it helps to remove and add the platform again:
`cordova platform rm android`
`cordova platform add android`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':\_armv7DebugCompile'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675491/could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-armv7debugcompile)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem!
I solved it with the following steps:

- Remove browser with `ionic browser revert android`
- Install crosswalk again `ionic browser add crosswalk`
- Deploy aplication `ionic run android`

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, on run time I used VPN in `ionic build android` and `Ionic run android` command. this will help to reach the website to download components.

Also about the maven

I run CMD command with "Run as Administrator" it started to download maven and after that it works fine for me.

Before this I used to upgrade JDK and JRE but has not change in result.

I have upgraded Windows 7 to Windows 10 directly and some times applications needs to start by using "Run As administrator"

Comment: You can't post your multiple answers. Just edit your first answer if you want to add more !

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution for the problem using the google play service and Google Repository in android SDK

Please install the following dependency using android SDK manager `Google Play services` and `Google Repository`

Once the installation is completed then you create your project and run.
Now it should work fine

[image]