# Crosswalk Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugCompile'

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

I successfully build my application with cordova until a few days ago with Crosswalk 18+, today I have this error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:18+.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
      > Failed to list versions for org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > peer not authenticated
      > Failed to list versions for org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > peer not authenticated
```

I've seen this other solution: [Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugCompile'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675491/could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-armv7debugcompile)

I installed already "Android support repository" and "Android support library" from SDK, I also made all available updates

Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
```

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/maven-metadata.xml = Not found for me

Cordova config.xml (a part):

```
<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="18+" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19"/>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

For some reason org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta:18+ don't work for me (same error):

```
<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta:18+" />
```

I checked the latest version on maven repo: 
https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library_beta/maven-metadata.xml

And i used a specific version (latest 18+):

```
<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta:18.48.477.11" />
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Crosswalk 18 stable is not released in maven repository, the latest stable version is 17.46.448.10:

https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library/maven-metadata.xml

You can also use a Crosswalk beta version at first but we will release Crosswalk 18 soon. Some examples:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview --variable XWALK_VERSION="org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta:18+"
<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta:18+" />
```

If you need to build one version not released in maven repo, we can install it to maven local repo:

```
wget https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/canary/<canary-version>/crosswalk-<canary-version>.aar
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.xwalk -DartifactId=xwalk_core_library -Dversion=<canary-version> -Dpackaging=aar -Dfile=<crosswalk-path>/crosswalk-<canary-version>.aar -DgeneratePom=true
```

Comment: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta:18+.
Why? This problem is very big for me, i need to build my app