# Cordova / Crosswalk Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugCompile'

Tags: cordova-plugins, crosswalk

cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview seems to be broken out-of-the-box. Tested with cordova 5.1.1 and 6.1.1 on OSX.

Solutions from [Crosswalk Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugCompile'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36552511/crosswalk-could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-armv7debugcomp) and [Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugCompile'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675491/could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-armv7debugcompile) did not work out.

```
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home
null
org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta:18+
Download https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library_beta/18.48.477.13/xwalk_core_library_beta-18.48.477.13.pom
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugCompile'.
   > Could not resolve org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library_beta:18+.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
      > Failed to move file '/private/var/folders/jr/3q77kjzd3yqfw_cllng_7c8c0000gn/T/gradle_download7281456311478481267bin'
```

- I checked e.g. the following: `Android Support Repository and`Google
  Repository`and even`Local Maven repository for Support` are
  installed
- Not working with cordova 5.1.? and 6.1.1 and various versions of
  crosswalk
- `PATH` and `ANDROID_HOME` are set

What do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the problem and the solution.

For some reason the following folders / file were owned by `root`, not my user such that building xwalk was prevented systemwide because of missing permissions.

Simply move the following to somewhere (delete also works) with sudo:

```
/Users/palinka/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.14/descriptors/org.xwalk
/Users/palinka/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.14/module-artifacts.bin
/Users/palinka/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.xwalk
```

We got additional debug output by compling with

```
gradle cdvBuildDebug -P android.useDeprecatedNdk=true --debug
```

in `platforms/android`.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you use default crosswalk version, so no need install in local. It's available in https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2/org/xwalk/xwalk_core_library_beta/18.48.477.13/.

From the log, it seems that 18.48.477.13 version is not found via network. It may be proxy issue, such as JAVA_OPTS, Gradle, Maven. You can check for whether need them.

Or you can share your steps, let me have a try, the build steps for cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview work well on my OSX.

Comment: It was not a download problem, it was the local filesystem permissions. Please see the solution to this thread.