# Ionic app shows white screen on android 4 versions

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, crosswalk-runtime

I am developing ionic application which works fine in browser as well in android 5 versions but when i try to install my same apk in andriod 4 versions it simply displays white screen doesnt show up anything.

i had tried installing crosswalk, whitelist and splash screen plugins after installing all plugins i am unable to build. i am attaching the screenshots of installed plugins and build error please help where i am going wrong.

[Please find the image where i installed the plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YjYt.png)

Also, Please find the error i am getting while building the app.

[Please find the build error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsCfH.png)

I am having the following in config.xml file

```
 <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
 <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="16" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, i found the solution to this issue.. 
Installed Crosswalk plugin which adds around 17MB to the app size then i tried installing Crosswalk Lite which worked well.

Here are few things you should look for in your config.xml :
                                                                                                             1. `<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>`

2.Most important is this one : 
I was using beta version of xwalk earlier

```
 <preference name="xwalkVersion" value="xwalk_core_library_beta:18+"/>
 <preference name="xwalkMode" value="embedded"/>
```

gives me apk of size around 33MB where actual app size is 11MB

now i am using canary version

```
<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="xwalk_core_library_canary:17+" />
<preference name="xwalkMode" value="lite" />
```

gives me apk of size around 21MB where actual app size is 11MB.

Please refer to thepio answer above it helped alot.

Comment: Awesome research! I might even use this by myself some day ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ionic officially supports Android versions 4.1.x and above. Your min SDK version is the required 4.1.x but are you testing on an older Android version like 4.0.x? You could set:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="15" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19" />
```

See this post on the official Ionic blog: http://blog.ionic.io/market-share-movement-android/

**EDIT based on your comment:**

You should see [this great answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33675539/2003702)

In the answer above they state that you should make sure you have Android Support Repository and Google Repository downloaded because crosswalk plugin is building two apks : one for ARM, the other for x86.

Comment: I guess you are using a Windows laptop since your terminal says it's an Acer Aspire. Am I right? And just to make sure you are trying to build the android platform?

Comment: I updated my answer because I found another question with an answer on SO which might be helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you ! and i am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS... i figured out the same solution ..it worked for me. but the apk file is quite huge after it worked. its around 30mb.

Comment: Yes it's known that crosswalk adds around ~17mb (if I remember correctly) to the apk size. If you wish to have a smaller apk size you could take a look at Crosswalk lite https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/crosswalk_lite.html

Comment: crosswalk lite increase the apk to same size.

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't used crosswalk in my apps so I can not help you with that. I'm sure you can find information about that issue from google or other SO posts?

Comment: i was using beta version of xwalk earlier

<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="xwalk_core_library_beta:18+"/>
<preference name="xwalkMode" value="embedded"/>

gives me apk of size around 33MB where actual app size is 11MB

now i am using canary version
<preference name="xwalkVersion" value="xwalk_core_library_canary:17+" />
<preference name="xwalkMode" value="lite" />

gives me apk of size around 21MB where actual app size is 11MB