# Ionic v1 app shows white screen on Android 6.1 (Marshmallow), Android 4.4 (KitKat) and Android 7.1(Nougat) after splashscreen

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, android-6.0-marshmallow, ionic-v1

I developed an Ionic application, which works fine in an Android version other than android version 6.0.1 (Marshmallow), Android 4.4 (KitKat) and Android 7.1(Nougat).

It shows a white screen after the splash screen loads. I refer some of the link but no luck. These are the links, which I referred:

- https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/white-page-showing-after-splash-screen-before-app-load/2908/19
- [Ionic app shows white screen on android 4 versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37344720/ionic-app-shows-white-screen-on-android-4-versions)

cli packages: (C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
Cordova Platforms : android 7.0.0
Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.0.0-rc.2
```

System:

```
Node : v8.11.3
npm  : 5.6.0
OS   : Windows 10
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : legacy
```

Plugin:

1. cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
2. cordova-plugin-console 1.1.0 "Console"
3. cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6 "Device"
4. cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
5. cordova-plugin-keyboard 1.1.5 "Keyboard"
6. cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.3 "Network Information"
7. cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
8. cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.3 "StatusBar"
9. cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"
   10 . cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.1.8 "SocialSharing"
10. cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.6.0 "Toast"
11. es6-promise-plugin 4.1.0 "Promise"

config.xml file

```
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-intent href="market:*" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

run function in app.js

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $timeout, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, $ionicHistory, $state) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    if (window.Connection) {
      if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
          title: 'No Internet Connection!',
          template: 'Sorry, no Internet connectivity detected. Please reconnect and Try again.'
        });
        alertPopup.then(function(res) {
          ionic.Platform.exitApp();
        });
      }
    }
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

Please help me with this. I was struggling to solve this issue for a week.

Comment: We faced the similar issue and our question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55244225/ionic-application-is-not-working-on-4-4-and-5-1

Comment: Check your min-sdk and also remove some of the plugin(trial and error method)

Answer (score 0):

try to add again all the plugins that you have added in project.Then again rebuild app.

Comment: Still same result

Comment: @ Santhosh K N <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25" /> add this to your AndroidManifest file.

Comment: @ Priyanka Wagh, thanks for your valuable suggestion. " <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25" /> " not working. But i need to share something. I started revert my codebase. Then i found the solution. When i remove the below function from my service.js file it working file.

Comment: .factory('PopupMessage', function($ionicPopup, ){
  return{
    confirmMessage:function(message){
      var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
        title: 'Dear User',
        template: message,
        scope: null,
        buttons: [{
          text: 'OK',
          type: 'button-calm',
          onTap: function(e) {
            return false;
          }
        }]
      });
    },
  }
})

Comment: @ Priyanka Wagh, is there any suggestion about above function please share.

Comment: .factory('PopupMessage', function($ionicPopup){ 
 return{ 

  confirmMessage:function(message){
  var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({ 
   title: 'Dear User', template: message, scope: null,
    buttons: [{ text: 'OK', type: 'button-calm', onTap: function(e) { 
     return false;

     } 
   }]
  }); 
 } 
 }
  })       try this@ Santhosh K N