# Ionic application is not working on 4.4 and 5.1

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

Ionic 4/3 application is showing white screen on Android Kitkat 4.4 and lolipop 5.1. My application is not working on kitkat and lolipop. I have installed on another Android version but it is working fine.
This is my config file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 
<widget id="com.novapex.myTestApp" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Test App</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="20" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-badge" spec="0.8.8" />
    <plugin name="es6-promise-plugin" spec="4.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="4.0.0" />
    <engine name="android" spec="7.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-android-support-gradle-release" spec="^2.0.1">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin> </widget>
```

plugins :

1. cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.8 "Badge"
2. cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
3. cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
4. cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.1.2 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
5. cordova-plugin-local-notification 0.9.0-beta.2 "LocalNotification"
6. cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 3.0.1 "Screen Orientation"
7. cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
8. cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
9. cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
10. cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.7.2 "Toast"
11. cordova-sqlite-storage 3.1.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin - cordova-sqlite-storage plugin version"
12. cordova-wheel-selector-plugin 1.0.0 "Cordova Wheel Selector Plugin"
13. es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
14. uk.co.workingedge.cordova.plugin.sqliteporter 1.1.0 "sqlite porter"

Comment: Could you please share error log?

Comment: @Maheshvirus I am getting these errors ( Viewport argument key "viewport-fit" not recognized and ignored. localhost/:10 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token = range.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: pre,template,textarea,script,style is not iterable! _for-of.js:14 )

Comment: For the error TypeError try this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834302/uncaught-typeerror-pre-template-textarea-script-style-is-not-iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834302/uncaught-typeerror-pre-template-textarea-script-style-is-not-iterable)

Answer (score 0):

`<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="20" />`
Android Kitkat API is level 19 , so this can't work. You need to downgrade your android-minSdkVersion

Comment: Dear i have same issue on Lolopop. I had implemented it before but its not working on 5.1.

Comment: I am getting these errors (  

Viewport argument key "viewport-fit" not recognized and ignored. localhost/:10
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token = range.js:2
Uncaught TypeError: pre,template,textarea,script,style is not iterable! _for-of.js:14 )

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncomment this lines in polyfill.ts

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

For me, now the ionic app works in android 5.0 e 5.1