# Ionic App Android SDK Issue - Failed to create directory /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2/temp

Tags: android, ionic-framework, sdk

I'm trying to build an Android app through Terminal. I'm not massively familiar with Terminal commands, however I've managed to build the iOS version successfully. When I try to compile for Android, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Please install Android target: "android-23".

Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2/bin/android
You will require:
1. "SDK Platform" for android-23
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)
```

If I open SDK Manager and try to install Android 6.0 (API 23), nothing installs -

```
Done loading packages.
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Documentation for Android SDK, API 23, revision 1
Failed to create directory /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2/temp
Downloading SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1
Failed to create directory /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2/temp
Downloading Samples for SDK API 23, revision 2
Failed to create directory /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2/temp
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 23, revision 1
Failed to create directory /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2/temp
Skipping 'Android TV ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 23, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23, revision 4'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 23, revision 5'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23, revision 5'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 23, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 23, revision 9'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23, revision 9'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 23, revision 14'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 23, revision 14'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23, revision 14'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 23, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Done. Nothing was installed.
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Documentation for Android SDK, API 23, revision 1
Failed to create directory /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2/temp
Downloading SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1
Failed to create directory /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2/temp
Downloading Samples for SDK API 23, revision 2
Failed to create directory /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2/temp
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 23, revision 1
Failed to create directory /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2/temp
Skipping 'Android TV ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 23, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23, revision 4'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 23, revision 5'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23, revision 5'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 23, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 23, revision 9'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23, revision 9'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 23, revision 14'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 23, revision 14'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23, revision 14'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 23, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Done. Nothing was installed.
Preparing to install archives
Downloading Documentation for Android SDK, API 23, revision 1
Failed to create directory /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2/temp
Downloading SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1
Failed to create directory /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2/temp
Downloading Samples for SDK API 23, revision 2
Failed to create directory /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2/temp
Downloading Sources for Android SDK, API 23, revision 1
Failed to create directory /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2/temp
Skipping 'Android TV ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 23, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android TV Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23, revision 4'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android Wear ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 23, revision 5'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23, revision 5'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 23, revision 3'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 23, revision 9'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23, revision 9'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs ARM EABI v7a System Image, Android API 23, revision 14'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image, Android API 23, revision 14'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 23, revision 14'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Skipping 'Google APIs, Android API 23, revision 1'; it depends on 'SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1' which was not installed.
Done. Nothing was installed.
```

I read a comment on another post ([Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_armv7DebugCompile'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675491/could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-armv7debugcompile)) where someone suggested posting the following (I'm guessing to check permissions), to help debug the problem:

```
Johns-iMac:Pastest johngoodwin$ sudo ls -ld /usr/local/Cellar
drwxr-xr-x  10 johngoodwin  admin  340 21 Nov  2014 /usr/local/Cellar
Johns-iMac:Pastest johngoodwin$ sudo ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 johngoodwin  admin  102 21 Nov  2014 android-sdk
drwxr-xr-x  3 johngoodwin  admin  102 21 Nov  2014 autoconf
drwxr-xr-x  3 johngoodwin  admin  102 21 Nov  2014 ios-sim
drwxr-xr-x  3 johngoodwin  admin  102 21 Nov  2014 node
drwxr-xr-x  3 johngoodwin  admin  102 21 Nov  2014 openssl
drwxr-xr-x  3 johngoodwin  admin  102 21 Nov  2014 pkg-config
drwxr-xr-x  3 johngoodwin  admin  102 21 Nov  2014 rbenv
drwxr-xr-x  3 johngoodwin  admin  102 21 Nov  2014 ruby-build
Johns-iMac:Pastest johngoodwin$ sudo ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  17 johngoodwin  admin  578 21 Nov  2014 23.0.2
Johns-iMac:Pastest johngoodwin$ sudo ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2 
total 72
-rw-r--r--   1 johngoodwin  admin   187 23 Sep  2014 INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
-rw-rw-r--   1 johngoodwin  wheel  1158  2 Jul  2014 README
lrwxr-xr-x   1 johngoodwin  admin    36 23 Sep  2014 add-ons -> ../../../var/lib/android-sdk/add-ons
drwxr-xr-x  25 johngoodwin  admin   850 21 Nov  2014 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 johngoodwin  admin   102 21 Nov  2014 build-tools
drwxr-xr-x  43 johngoodwin  admin  1462 21 Nov  2014 docs
drwxr-xr-x   3 johngoodwin  admin   102 21 Nov  2014 etc
lrwxr-xr-x   1 johngoodwin  admin    35 23 Sep  2014 extras -> ../../../var/lib/android-sdk/extras
drwxr-xr-x  12 johngoodwin  admin   408 21 Nov  2014 platform-tools
lrwxr-xr-x   1 johngoodwin  admin    38 23 Sep  2014 platforms -> ../../../var/lib/android-sdk/platforms
lrwxr-xr-x   1 johngoodwin  admin    36 23 Sep  2014 samples -> ../../../var/lib/android-sdk/samples
lrwxr-xr-x   1 johngoodwin  admin    36 23 Sep  2014 sources -> ../../../var/lib/android-sdk/sources
lrwxr-xr-x   1 johngoodwin  admin    42 23 Sep  2014 system-images -> ../../../var/lib/android-sdk/system-images
lrwxr-xr-x   1 johngoodwin  admin    33 23 Sep  2014 temp -> ../../../var/lib/android-sdk/temp
drwxr-xr-x  29 johngoodwin  wheel   986 21 Nov  2014 tools
```

Can anyone provide a solution to the problem please? I'm tearing my hair out!

Many thanks,

John.

Comment: I've also tried installing SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1 via Terminal, using the following: 

sudo android update sdk -u -a -t 25 

but I get a similar error: 

Installing Archives:
  Preparing to install archives
  Downloading SDK Platform Android 6.0, API 23, revision 1
  Failed to create directory /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2/temp
  Done. Nothing was installed.

Answer (score 0):

Download Android SDK Tools from http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools

Extract in /home/{{user}}/build/

Insert below code at ~/.profile (caution: do not remove anything from there, just append this code)

```
 //set PATH so it includes android SDK toold
 if [ -d "$HOME/build" ] ; then
 ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/build/android-sdk
 PATH="ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH"
 fi
```

Please let me know if this suggestion solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'm afraid it hasn't made any difference.

Did you mean to add the code in ~/.profile, or ~/.bash_profile? I tried adding it in my bash profile, with no improvement. I don't have a ~/.profile. I tried creating one, and added your code in, but that didn't help either. :/

Comment: I mean in ~/.profile. Are you sure you don't have?What os are you using?Do you download the Android SDK Tools? Is the folder in the rigth path and the name of the folder android-sdk?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the existing temp@ symbolic link from the folder `/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/23.0.2/`